# Clicking a dynamic button with Playwright: How to identify by class name

Tags: web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

[image]

How can I use Playwright to click on the button in the image, identified by its class name? It's important to note that the button's name changes daily, starting with 'Collect 10 Candies' and incrementing by *2 each day, before resetting every week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
page.query_selector("button[data-action='click->points#claimCandy'][data-target='points.button']").click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your locator for that class can be this:

```
.collect-candy-button
```

so:

```
page.locator(`.collect-candy-button`).click()
```

Comment: Will this syntax work for Python? It's giving me a syntax highlight error

Comment: Maybe it does not like the back ticks ` . Try replacing with apostropies:
`page.locator('.collect-candy-button').click()`

Comment: Still didn't work for me. I guess it might work for those using Node.js